# How do I make my python script not crash on a wrong Popen command?

Tags: python, crash, command, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to work with subprocess.popen and it works great.
The only problem is that my entire script crashes when i type for example "iffconfig" instead of "ifconfig"
How do I make sure it doesn't crash on a wrong command, and just reply with the error message instead? Just point me in the right direction. 
example code:

```
    command = "ifconfig" #this command is actually requested so you can make a typo which causes it to crash
    temp = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = temp.stdout.read()
    out.replace("\r", "\n")
    outlist = out.split("\n")
    for line in outlist:
        print(line)
```

thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Handling Exceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) page in the python documentation.

You can use a `try-except` block to catch errors, and do some pretty output, instead of a crash.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll have  look at it :)

Comment: No problem bro!